# Vector geometry problem including skew lines, plane, and light ray.

Tags: geometry, vectors

I found this problem in one dusty textbook and thought I'd give it a try, but I can't seem to be able to solve it. I need your help.

Basically, you are given a point $P$ in the normal $x,y,z$ coordinate system with coordinates $P (1,5,0)$. You are also given lines $a$ and $b$ with equations 
$$a:\begin{cases}x = 1-2t\\ y = 2+t\\ z = 2t \end{cases}\qquad b:\begin{cases}x+y-5 = 0\\ 3x-2z-9 = 0 \end{cases}$$
Also the equation of the plane $R: y-z-2 = 0$.

What needs to be done is to find the equation of a light ray which passes through point $P$, reflects off the plane $R$ and its reflection passes through lines $a$ and $b$.

My line of thoughts went by finding the orthogonal projections of the points in which the reflection intersects with $a$ and $b$ and then build points with equivalent length from the orthogonal projections (basically to continue $l$ through the plane) but couldn't seem to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For $b$ you have given the equations of two planes, not the equation of a line as such

Comment: That's not true, it's a euqtion of a line, just written in a different way.

Comment: $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is the equation of a plane. Two non-parallel planes intersect in a line. That's what you have with the set of equations you have denoted as $b$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. What I meant is that by typing it as b : (insert equations here) it's implied that b is the line where they intersect, and as such b could easily be converted to scalar-parametric quation for example. Also sorry I didnt mean to be rude if it came out that way

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1

> Consider $P'$ the reflection of $P$ by the plane $R$.

Hint 2

> Instead of a ray through $P$, look for a line through $P'$ that intersects both lines $a$ and $b$.

Those two above should get you started, but if you need some more:

Hint 3

> Line $a$ and point $P'$ define a plane, have a look at it.

If you really really need some more:

Hint 4

> The plane in Hint 3 will in general intersect line $b$. (If it doesn't, there's no solution to your problem.)

Hint 5

> Let's call the point of intersection from Hint 4 $I$. What can you say of the line through $I$ and $P'$?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, hadn't thought of projecting P down. I solved it, with hints 1 to 3. You really helped me out. It feels bad I can't give you karma :/